# Height 100% not working on any device

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I've encountered a bug on a website I'm making, where my sidebar background will not cover the whole height on any device. I've tried giving the elements before it 100% height, and have looked through many similar posts but none of their solutions fixing my issue. The site is at https://minepos.piggypiglet.me, and I can supply the code in a hastebin if requested, but dev tools should suffice?

[image: bug]

html: https://hastebin.com/ovitaroxen.xml
css: https://hastebin.com/cocuketino.css
Sorry for the links, there was too much to include in code blocks.

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS and HTML to your question.

Comment: I don't have an accounI to access "minepos", can you post your code please.

Comment: _" I can supply the code in a hastebin if requested"_ No, you need to post a [mcve] in your question, not a third party site. See [ask]

Comment: Don't use `height:100%` unless all parent elements are `100%`, which in your case are not. Use `height:100vh`

Comment: you can use `height: 100vh` for doing your task

Comment: This is just a frontend, simply click login. I'm adding examples now. Will first try vh though.

Comment: Just added code links, there were too many characters to include the code in the post. The vh thing didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vh` for doing your task.

```
div {
   height: 100vh /*100% of device height*/
}
```

This is you can use for responsive designs.

Comment: @KobyDouek if it IS an answer, it's acceptable.

Comment: Some questions are better left unanswered until the "question is [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)"

Comment: @ZimSystem ok. I am new to StackOverflow. thanks for advice me.